# Repointing iTunes library from failed external drive to local drive

Tags: itunes, libraries

Up until recently I had my iTunes library on an external drive, but the drive was beginning to act up, so as a precaution, I copied all the media files onto my local hard-drive.

My external drive is now completely dead, so I'm in a situation where iTunes is still looking for the files on my F: drive, but the drive is gone, so the library references are now all broken links.

A complete copy of the library is on my C: drive, so I'm curious what would be the easiest way to repoint my library to the media files on C:?

Should I just clear out my library in iTunes and just import the files from C:?  Or is there a more automatic way?  I don't think I can use the "Consolidate Library" function in iTunes, b/c I no longer have access to the original library media files.

Answer (score 2):

Under the Advanced Tab in iTune's preferences, you can change the location of your iTunes folder.  Doing so should cause iTunes to find your media library in its new location.